# angularjs and Twitter bootstrap conflict?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

can i use angularjs with Twitter bootstrap or not?
I try to create a simple app and no conflict  between angular and bootstrap, so why does ui-bootstrap exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular JS will work with bootstrap, but its ok to do this only when AngularJS does not try to manipulate the bootstrap elements (E.g: Modal)

**Reason:**

Bootstrap is based on JQuery, suppose you want to do some modifications to the bootstrap elements(E.g: Modal which works on JQuery) using angular, you will start facing issues, because Bootstrap's(JQuery) javascript which takes care of this, exists outside the angular framework, because of this, when you update a variable in angularJS you will experience multiple issues, like variables not updating immediately and other issues.

**Solution:**

To tackle this, the Internet Gurus have given us a vast collection of plugins/directives for using these JQuery plugins in our angular application. This plugin acts as the middle man and will sync up AngularJS with JQuery code. Some of the plugins may have the whole library rewritten.

**Conclusion:**

So please refrain from implementing JQuery code directly in an angular application. Scour the internet for a suitable plugin for it, it will save you lots of time debugging unwanted issues!